# File chunking and buffering?

Tags: c

Ultimately I'm just looking to cut a binary file into pieces no greater than X in size. Do no else with it. If the input file is 21MB, I want 3 pieces of 7MB I could join with cat or what not.I In the simple example below that works, I'm using a 7MB chunk size buffer. Do I have to use that at all to get 7MB file chunks? If the chunk size was say 2GB, that is obviously not something I want to put in memory. So do I need to create a buffer at all.

I did reads several posts on here and other sites about this, but they all seem to use some sort of buffer created by malloc or arrays, and looking up non-buffered ways lead me too far ahead of my knowledge into sockets and TCP/IP related topics.

Am I doomed to a whole lot of if/while statements?

P.S. Where can I find books on I/O streams in C? I can find a LOT for C++, but not C.

```
ifp = fopen(ifile, "rb"); // ifile is a 25MB sound file
ofp = fopen(ofile, "w");  // Omitted error checking.

setvbuf( ifp, NULL, _IOFBF, 1024); // Are these on
setvbuf( ofp, NULL, _IOFBF, 1024); // by default?

size_t CHUNK = 7000000;  // 7MB Chunk sizes
size_t result = 0;
size_t *buffer = malloc(CHUNK);

if (buffer == NULL) {fputs ("Could not allocate memory",stderr); exit (1);}
// Read 1 btye at a time?
result = fread(buffer, 1, CHUNK, ifp);
if (result != CHUNK) {fputs ("ERROR: Buffer/read mismatch.",stderr); exit (1);}

fwrite(buffer, CHUNK, 1, ofp);

free(buffer);
```

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  Not the chunking/buffering description, but the high-level description of 'the purpose of this exercise is to ... hold the whole file in memory ... or ... compress the file ... or ... what?'

Comment: Just cut it up into pieces. I don't need to keep it in memory for any comparisons or anything, or compress for output.

Comment: When you say 'cut it up into pieces', what do you mean?  Create N little files of not more than 7 MiB each from a file of perhaps 2 GiB?

Comment: @JustTired It's impossible to give you any advice, since we don't know what you want to do with the files. Copy them ? Send them over a network ? Sort the lines in them ? Count words in them ? All we see is some code which doesn't solve a problem.

Comment: Also, where do you find `I_BUFFER` and `O_BUFFER`; they are non-standard constants, and `O_BUFFER` is a name treading on thin ice since POSIX reserves names starting `O_` when you include `<fcntl.h>`.

Comment: Sorry, yes. I just want files no more than 7MB files each. Yes, sorry, sorry again. It was too obvious too me to realize it wouldn't be to anyone else.

Comment: OK —— please update your question to explain what you're after so that anyone who comes along can understand from reading the question (without having to wade though all the comments).  Then we can look into cleaning up this comment trail.

Comment: Your code only shows copying the first 7MB, do you intend to write more to another file, or just leave the rest off? Why Are you cutting the file into pieces?

Comment: @JustTired So, you want to split 1 big file into smaller files, each of 7Mb ? (use a loop, read a piece from the big file, write it to the small file, open another one when you've written 7Mb)

Comment: Why do you need to read a 7MB chunk at a time? Can't you just read it with a more normal buffer size until you've copied 7MB to a new file, then start the next file?

Comment: If you don't mind not going through the process of reinventing the wheel and are willing to use other people's work, then the POSIX command [`split`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/split.html) can do what you're after from the command line.

Comment: @Johnathan - I agree the OP is spinning his wheels in the mud, but I don't see  a UNIX/Linux tag on the question.

Comment: @nos The ways I have learned so far are to count each byte to determine size.

Comment: Use stat() to determine the size of the original file.

Comment: @Troy define "normal buffer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a program, `bsplit`, that I originally wrote in 1991.  It splits a file up into arbitrary sized chunks; the default size is specified in kilobytes (well, [kibibytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte) — 1024 bytes).

```
/*
@(#)File:           $RCSfile: bsplit.c,v $
@(#)Version:        $Revision: 1.11 $
@(#)Last changed:   $Date: 2008/08/09 05:54:55 $
@(#)Purpose:        Split file into blocks -- binary
@(#)Author:         J Leffler
*/

#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
#else
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#endif /* __STDC_VERSION__ */

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "stderr.h"
#include "filter.h"

#define MAXFILENAMELEN  256
#define KILOBYTE 1024
#define MEGABYTE (KILOBYTE*KILOBYTE)
#define GIGABYTE (MEGABYTE*KILOBYTE)
#define NIL(x)  ((x)0)
#define MIN(a,b)    (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))

char    *prefix = "bsplit.";
size_t   blocksize = 64;
size_t   nblocks = 0;
size_t   skipblocks = 0;
char     buffer[64*KILOBYTE];
long     counter = 0;

static int  bsplit(FILE *ifp, const char *fn)
{
    size_t   n;         /* Bytes read this time */
    size_t   bsize;     /* Size written for current block */
    size_t   tsize;     /* Size written for current file */
    size_t   rsize;     /* Amount to read */
    FILE    *op;        /* Output file stream */
    char     file[MAXFILENAMELEN];  /* Output file name */

    tsize = 0;
    bsize = 0;
    op = NIL(FILE *);
    rsize = MIN(sizeof(buffer), blocksize);
    while ((n = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), rsize, ifp)) > 0)
    {
        tsize += n;
        if (tsize > skipblocks)
        {
            if (bsize == 0)
            {
                sprintf(file, "%s%03ld", prefix, counter++);
                if ((op = fopen(file, "w")) == NIL(FILE *))
                {
                    err_sysrem2("failed to open file", file);
                    return(-1);
                }
                printf("%s\n", file);
            }
            bsize += n;
            if (fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), n, op) != n)
            {
                err_sysrem2("failed to write to file", file);
                return(-1);
            }
            if (bsize >= blocksize)
            {
                fclose(op);
                bsize = 0;
            }
            if (nblocks > 0 && tsize >= nblocks)
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int opt;
    size_t multiplier = KILOBYTE;
    char *p;
    char  c;
    int   rc;

    opterr = 0;
    err_setarg0(argv[0]);

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "s:n:p:b:V")) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 'p':
            prefix = optarg;
            if (strlen(prefix) > MAXFILENAMELEN - sizeof("000"))
                err_error("file name prefix (%s) is too long (max %d)", prefix,
                          (int)(MAXFILENAMELEN-sizeof("000")));
            break;
        case 's':
            skipblocks = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 'n':
            nblocks = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 'b':
            blocksize = atoi(optarg);
            p = optarg + strspn(optarg, "0123456789");
            if (*p != '\0')
            {
                c = tolower((unsigned char)*p);
                if (c == 'c')
                    multiplier = 1;
                else if (c == 'b')
                    multiplier = KILOBYTE/2;
                else if (c == 'k')
                    multiplier = KILOBYTE;
                else if (c == 'm')
                    multiplier = MEGABYTE;
                else if (c == 'g')
                    multiplier = GIGABYTE;
                else
                    err_error("unknown size multiplier suffix %s\n", p);
                if (p[1] != '\0')
                    err_error("unknown size multiplier suffix %s\n", p);
            }
            break;
        case 'V':
            err_version("BSPLIT", &"@(#)$Revision: 1.11 $ ($Date: 2008/08/09 05:54:55 $)"[4]);
            break;
        default:
            err_usage("[-b blocksize][-p prefix][-s skipblocks][-n blocks][file [...]]");
            break;
        }
    }

    /* Convert sizes to bytes */
    blocksize  *= multiplier;
    skipblocks *= blocksize;
    if (nblocks > 0)
        nblocks = skipblocks + nblocks * blocksize;

    rc = filter_stdout(argc, argv, optind, bsplit);
    return(rc);
}
```

The header `stderr.h` declares a series of error reporting routines; I use it in most of my programs.  The header `filter.h` declares the function `filter_stdout()` which steps through an argument list, opening the files for reading and calling a function — in this case `bsplit()` — to process each file in turn.  It handles 'no arguments means read standard input' etc automatically.  (Contact me for the code — see my profile.)

Note that the multiplier `c` means 'characters', `b` means 512-byte blocks, and `k`, `m`, and `g` mean KiB, MiB and GiB respectively.

---

The support code is now available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `filter.c`, `filter.h`, `filterio.c`, `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.  There's also a header `posixver.h` which would replace the `__STDC_VERSION__` stanza — and would use `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` rather than `600` to request POSIX.1 2008 (2018) support.

Comment: Thank you for this! This helps in a few ways for a beginner like me :-). The NIL(X), I thought a FILE * had to be set specifically to "NULL". Learned something before I even got to the actual code :-).

Comment: Oh gosh — is there still a NIL(x) in there?  That's an old, old trick that I used 15+ years ago and thought I'd excised...from most of my code it is gone, but evidently not this program.  I haven't done much more than casual maintenance on it for the last decade (the last big change was in 2003, to add the multipliers).  The macro certainly works, but it is not necessary.  (It was more important before C89 was standardized, especially on the machine I learned C on, where the `char *` address was different from the `short *` (or any other longer type) address for the same memory location.)

Answer (score 1):

```
setvbuf( ifp, NULL, _IOFBF, I_BUFFER); // Are these on
setvbuf( ofp, NULL, _IOFBF, O_BUFFER); // by default?
```

These set the file buffer to be "fully buffered", which means that data is only written when the buffer (defined by I_BUFFER and O_BUFFER) is full.

I would also suggest that you don't need to read a large amount at a time. 10-100KB would be more than enough to reduce any overhead in the OS to next to nothing, and the loop to do this a few times will be such a small proportion it won't matter. If you read smaller portions and then write out the small portion, you may even get a bit of overlap, where if you read 7MB in one go, it will take long enough that a previous write of 7MB has probably finished completely by the time the 7MB has been read.

All of the C standard library is covered at www.cplusplus.com (despite the name, it covers C functions just as well as C++ functions).

Comment: I keep reading that about setvbuf, but what does "only written when the bufffer is full" mean. Does this mean every time I call fread(), fread() waits for the BUFFER to fill first?

Comment: It means that there is a buffer internally in the ifp and ofp, which is just to "pre-read" and "offload" the data. So when you write to the ofp, it won't call the OS immediately for every write, but when the buffer is full - so if the buffer is 32KB, it will do 7M / 32K actual writes to the OS. For reads, it won't read more than a buffer at a time, but it may read a whole buffer when you ask for 1 byte or 1KB - or it may not. Depends on the C library implementation. I do agree with Jens - no need to actually mess with these things, in general.

Comment: If you're using `fread()` and 'large' read sizes (say 4 KiB or bigger), the buffering on the file stream is immaterial.  For some power of 2 usually between 512 and 4096, the standard I/O library reads in chunks of up to that size as data becomes available.  The crucial point for standard I/O buffering is that it reduces the cost of single-character I/O (`getc()`, `putc()`) and short I/O (`fgets()`, `fputs()` in typical scenarios) by avoiding a system call per I/O operation, so it will buffer up to the buffer size characters before doing a system call to read or write the data.

Comment: I understand. Kind of like a mug that has to be filled by the tap before you can drink it, spill it, break it or whatever, the tap being the OS.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about buffering at all. The Standard C library developers have done this already for you. You will not lose much performance even if you read character by character with `fgetc()` and write with `fputc()`. These usually are macros to access the buffered stdio structures.

I trust I don't have to tell you how to write a loop that reads and writes by character and switches to a new file after the desired number of bytes.

To make it explicit again: The first rule of optimization: **don't**. The second: measure before you do.